# Asymmetry in `satisfies` operator behaviour

Tags: typescript

Im reading about how typescript satisfies operator works and what caught my attention was a bit asymetric behaviour of typescript. Lets take a look at typical tutorial example fo `satisfies` usage.

```
type stringOrNumber = string | number; 

const user : { name : stringOrNumber} = {
    name: 'John'
}

user.name.toUpperCase();  //error 

const userThatSatisfies = {
    name : 'John'
} satisfies { name : stringOrNumber}; 

userThatSatisfies.name.toUpperCase();  //works
```

This is reasonable. Typescript is unable to know if `stringOrNumber` is actually `string` or `number` and this is source of problem that `satisfies` solves.

But all of this is true only if name is nested as property of user object. If we take a look at flat example.

```
type stringOrNumber = string | number; 

const userName : stringOrNumber = 'John'; 

userName.toUpperCase();
```

Situation is similar, we have variable that is either string or number but now typescript is able to properly work without `satisfies`. Do you understand the source of behaviour like this?

Here is [code playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAzsBOBLAdgcwPLwHIFcC2ARhPFALywIqpQA%20Uy%20R8A3FAFBsDGA9snFDhjEsAQzzQAXBSRpMuQsTJQA5ACluAC2TLWHHn2AChJKQG96YydKpzGxAL5LTbKK4vipa7qm1t7HQWFLADpgbgAZbgB3YgBhESEACgBKXTZA%20GDkELCAVTBIeHik1PYuXn4MgBUNEWAAZTrEGAAzRAgYJxc3bPEoT3UtZT9YJtb2zvNeqzgZDGw7eHs06tqGsbaOrJzufMLiiBS0oA)

Comment: This isn't related to `satisfies`. The last code block works because at assignment time it's *known* whether it's a string or number - a string is being assigned. Thus TS narrows the type to string. Since it's a `const` it won't change.

Comment: change to `let` then to allow mutation. It will still work. The first code block also known at the time of assignment that user.name is `string`.

Comment: If you never re-assign a `let`, TS considers this effectively constant. So a `let x: number | string = "hello"` is narrowed to a string. Unless it's reassigned.

Comment: Yes, but could do the same with nested property user.name. Here is asymmetry. This was the post about. What is the source of this, why nested property is treated differently.

Comment: [Assignment narrowing](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) happens when assigning directly to a union, not to an object with a union-typed property.  Your top case doesn't narrow because it's a single object type (with a union property). Your bottom case does narrow because it's a union.  That's the difference; `satisfies` is mostly a red herring here; `satisfies` changes the behavior because you're not narrowing, just checking against a wider type. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I mentioned already I understand what happen, Im asking why here is this assymetry. What is the motivation behind such language design. I dont think someone decided to have things bahaving differently just because its funny.

Comment: I guess we're at an impasse.  Assignment narrowing is a documented feature, it works on unions.  There is no "asymmetry" to speak of: you're doing different things and seeing different behaviors.  All I can give you is links to the official documentation, which is the closest to a "motivation behind such language design" you'll get unless you want the language designers to come here an post the answer themselves.  What more can be said?  Maybe I just don't understand the criteria by which you would decide whether an answer is correct or incorrect?  Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Definitely you could understand this, because there can be hidden problem we dont see. Difference is that I try to understand you do not. Impasee indeed.